# Likes on archived pages with different url

Tags: facebook, url, href, facebook-like

On our site we are moving pages to an archive with a different domain, say `arch.domain.com/123123-page.html` (arch. is the archive subdomain). The original page will use a 302 redirect to the archive page.

The original pages have likes and shares on Facebook. I want to know how to keep these likes count visible after moving the pages to the archive?

The `og:url` and `data-href` both point to original page on archived pages - `domain.com/123123-page.html`. This do not keep the likes number, and actually breaks the like button.

Is it possible to maintain the likes while moving the page?

Comment: The original URL has to still be available to Facebook’s scraper and serve the relevant Open Graph meta data to it.

Comment: so 301 or 302 will not work?

so if we detect user-agent and serve to facebook page content instead of redirect, this will work?
/* just want to be sure before bothering developer ))) */

Comment: Likes are bound to the URL they were made on initially – so if you want to keep old likes, you have to keep old og:url as well. (Why) has your _developer_ not done their own research on this yet …?

Comment: as I said

>> og:url and data-href both point to original page on archived pages

but it's just do not work.

---
developer has no idea about likes, facebook, etc. that's not his job.

Comment: And is the original URL still active and delivers the meta data? (Without redirecting anywhere else, and with the og:url set to itself)?

Comment: no ((
Original page use 302 redirect to archive page.

archive page use original or:url

Comment: Well that of course creates a “redirect loop”. See to it, that the Facebook Scraper gets excluded from the redirect.